# stuck on list update: list indices must be intiger

Tags: python, python-2.7

So far I have written this code and I got stuck on list update. I tried different ways, also with for loop, but I couldn't solve it.

```
print "hello, welcome to"
a_list=["1. Add a new word","2. Update and existing word","3. Detele and existing word","4. Display a words definition"]
zero=0
empt_list=[]
empt_list_meaning=[]
def list_game():
    for i in a_list:
        print i
    a_options=input("Please select one of these options: ")
    if a_options== 1:
        a_newword=raw_input("What word you want to add? ")
        empt_list.append(a_newword)
        a_newword_meaning=raw_input("add the meaning of the word")
        empt_list_meaning.append(a_newword_meaning)
        # print a_list[a_options-1]
        print empt_list,a_newword,"added correctly"

    elif a_options == 2:
        a_update=raw_input("select a word to update:")
        a_renew_word = raw_input("the new word")
        if a_update in empt_list:
            empt_list[a_update]=a_renew_word
        else:
            print "sorry"
        # print a_list[a_options-1]

    elif a_options == 3:
        a_del_word=raw_input("selct the word you want to delete")
        for i in empt_list:
            if a_del_word in empt_list:
                empt_list.remove(a_del_word)
        # print a_list [a_options-1]


    elif a_options  == 4:
        for i in empt_list:
            print i
    print ("would you like to continue or exit?\n1.contine\n2.exit")
    now=input(">>> ")
    if now==1:
        list_game()
    else:
        print "arrivederchi"
list_game()
```

Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Umer Selmani/Desktop/newproject2018.py", line 44, in <module>
    list_game()
  File "C:/Users/Umer Selmani/Desktop/newproject2018.py", line 41, in list_game
    list_game()
  File "C:/Users/Umer Selmani/Desktop/newproject2018.py", line 22, in list_game
    empt_list[a_update]=a_renew_word
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: You should post complete 'traceback'. Where is the error? What is this code doing or supposed to do?

Comment: @Austin i did update, you can have a check now. thank you

Answer (score 0):

I assume it is this bit that is causing trouble. `a_update` is a string, not an integer. List indices must be an integer. Try the updated code below:

```
elif a_options == 2:
    a_update=raw_input("select a word to update:")
    # Note a_update is a string that user enters
    a_renew_word = raw_input("the new word")
    if a_update in empt_list:
        # This bit is changed from empt_list[a_update] to...
        empt_list.index(a_update)=a_renew_word
    else:
        print "sorry"
    # print a_list[a_options-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting coz of this part of the code,

```
elif a_options == 2:
        a_update=raw_input("select a word to update:")
        a_renew_word = raw_input("the new word")
        if a_update in empt_list:
            empt_list[a_update]=a_renew_word
        else:
            print "sorry"
        # print a_list[a_options-1]
```

Since list indices must be integers, you should have an integer passed as a list index in the below code. Below is one more way to do it,

```
if a_update in empt_list:
        #updated code
        lst_index=empt_list.index(a_update)
        empt_list[lst_index]=a_renew_word
    else:
        print "sorry"
```

The way you have mentioned could have worked, if the empt_list was a dictionary but not list. Since dictionaries stores data in the form of key, value pairs so they can take both integers and strings as keys.